# How to works with two json formats with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have class with field `names`:

```
private List<String> names;
```

Json that I'm getting looks like:

```
"names": [
 {
   "name": "a",
 },
 {
   "name": "b",
 },
 {
   "name": "c",
 }
]
```

So I use custom serializing for transform this json to List:

```
@JsonProperty("names")
private void deserializeNames(List<Map<String, String>> json) {
    names = json.stream().map(e -> e.get("name")).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And this solution works, but when I will want to serialize objects of my class, new json will looks like:

```
"names": [
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

And my code for custom serializing won't work with it because it expects `Map` instead `List`

I tried to solve the problem using `instanceof` or deserialize list to map, but I think this is a wrong solution.
Is there any easy solutions for this problem?

Comment: Json and class field does not match , that field will not produce Json like that.

Comment: @amer yes, I understand it. But I'm interesting to find solution for working with both formats at the same time

Comment: My advice is not to use `List<Map<String, String>> json` for list of names , there is no need for that , use only `List<String>` or if you have to `<Map<String, String>`. 
But to use List od Maps is overkill.

Comment: @amer this is format of data that I m getting from third-party source. I don't control it.

Comment: Then try something like this:
`Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
  for(String name:json){
    map.put("name",name);
  }`

Comment: BTW, your JSON format is invalid, there are redundant commas in the end of `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need not write custom Deserialiser for this,
You can define a class,

```
class Name {
   @JsonProperty("name")
   String name;
   Name () {
   }
}
```

You can use,

```
@JsonProperty("names")
private List<Name> names;
```

This will deserialise automatically. While serialising it will do the same.